# How to update object data of parent in child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am making custom component for dropdown. I have one config object which I am initializing in `ngOnInit()`, and I am combining the default configs and configs provided by user as an `@Input()`, But at run time from parent component, If I am making any changes in my config object, it is not updating in `ngOnChanges()` method of my child.

I tried this:

> child component

```
@Input() config: MyConfig;
        @Input() disabled: boolean
        
        ngOnChanges() {
                console.log('config', this.config); // this is not
                console.log('disabled', this.disabled); // this is detecting
            }
```

> parent component html

```
<button (click)="changeConfig()">Change Config</button>
<app-child [config]="customConfig" [disabled]="newDisabled"></app-child>
```

> parent component ts

```
newDisabled = false;
customConfig = {
        value: 'code',
        label: 'name',
        floatLabel: 'Select'
    };

changeConfig() {
    this.customConfig.value = 'name';
    this.newDisabled = true;
}
```

for disbale variable it is working, but for config it is not, Am I doing something wrong? please help

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you `ngOnInit` is setting the `config` variable to a new object. Since the `@Input()` is called once, this breaks your reference to the original object, and changes will not be detected.

You can fix this by using a setter and getter. I have added a stack blitz to demo this bellow.

[Blockquote](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-avvufa?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

parent component

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  newDisabled = false;
  customConfig = {
    value: 'code',
    label: 'name',
    floatLabel: 'Select',
  };

  changeConfig1() {
    this.customConfig.value = 'name1';
    this.newDisabled = true;
    console.log('Change Config 1');
  }

  changeConfig2() {
    this.customConfig.value = 'name2';
    this.newDisabled = true;
    console.log('Change Config 2');
  }
}
```

child component

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

class MyConfig {}

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1> config: {{config | json}}</h1><h1> disabled: {{disabled}}</h1>`,
  styles: [],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  private _defaultConfig = {
    key: 'default',
  };

  @Input() disabled: boolean;

  private _config: MyConfig;
  @Input() config: MyConfig;
  set () {
    if (!this.config) {
      this.config = new MyConfig(); // it is a class
    } else {
      this._config = {
        ...this.config,
        ...this._defaultConfig,
      };
    }
  }
  get () {
    return this._config;
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('config', this.config);
    console.log('config', this._config);
    console.log('disabled', this.disabled);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Input object are compared by reference, so if you want to reflect changes in your child component and trigger `ngOnChanges` do this:

```
changeConfig() {
 this.customConfig = {...this.customConfig, value: 'name'};;
 this.newDisabled = true;
}
```

And also move your below code from `ngOnInit` to `ngOnChanges`, chances are that at the time of initialisation input chagnes may not be available.

```
if (!this.config) {
   this.config = new MyConfig(); // it is a class
 } else  {
    this.config = {
           ...this._defaultConfig,
           ...this.config
          };
 }
```

Comment: can we do it by `ngDoCheck()`,? I tried ngDoCheck also, but didn't worked for me

Comment: But is it correct to override entire object, when I required to change only one key? is there any optimize way to do the same?

Comment: Yeah, u can detect changes by creating a service and `subscribe` to the variable by using `BehaviourSubject` but that also comes with additional overhead. That's the two options you have.

Comment: Can't we do it with ngDoCheck() ?

Comment: check [this](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#docheck). There is no reason to complicate things unnecessary. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the change detection is only triggered if the object `customConfig` is changed. In you example, only the `value` property is updated. What you can do is the following in the `parent.component.ts`:

```html
changeConfig() {
    this.customConfig = Object.assign(this.customConfig, { value: 'name'});
    this.newDisabled = true;
}
```

This will create a **new** config object which contains the updated `value` property and all the other old properties of the old `customConfig`.

Comment: But is it correct to override entire object, when I required to change only one key? is there any optimize way to do the same?

Comment: Otherwise you can pass each individual property of the `cutomConfig` as a separate `@Input()` to the other config, or at least the ones that change regularly.

Comment: Can't we do it with ngDoCheck() ?

Comment: Probably, but I never used it and running a function on each change detection cycle is probably much more costly than just copying a object.